# Laravel Chumper/Zipper removing names of files

Tags: php, laravel

I've recently installed Chumper/Zipper and trying to upload files into a zip file. However, when I open up the zip file all the files uploaded have been renamed and file extensions are removed. For example when I upload an image as image.png it will change to php20V2Wx. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

**Method for storing the file**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    foreach ( $request->files as $files ){
         \Zipper::make(public_path('tests.zip'))->add($files)->close();
    }

    return response()->download(public_path('tests.zip'));
}
```

**$files  output**

> Array ( [0] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile
>   Object (
>   [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
>   [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private]
>   => favicon.ico [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private]
>   => image/x-icon [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
>   5686
>   [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
>   0 [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/php4tQEul
>   [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => php4tQEul ) )

Comment: Can you print `$files` before you add to check what does it contain

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam sure added it above

Comment: do add($files, 'FILNAME')

Comment: @Bugfixer Thanks added the following code and seems to work now:           $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();    and  ->add($file,$filename);